# C++ JNI wants to install Mac Legacy JRE6

Tags: java, c++, macos, java-native-interface

I have JDK8 installed and my JAVA_HOME is set to the correct path for that. I can use Java without any problems. However, when I try to run Java code from C++, it prompts me to install a really old version of JRE6.

In my code I have:

```
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
```

so it is weird that JRE6 is being requested. How can I get C++ JNI to use my existing JDK8 installation?

[image: JDK8 is installed, but JRE6 is promoted to install.]

Comment: A wild guess: this is 32-bit code?

Comment: Recompile the native JNI code against the newer version of Java?

Comment: Is that your own code? I.e. do you have influence over what libraries it links against?

Comment: Yes, it is my code and I am just using JDK 8's jni.h. I went through everything and it doesn't seem like anything is 32bit and the java class was compiled using jdk8 javac.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this happens when code uses `libjvm.dylib`. There's also `libjli.dylib` which has the same functions but skips the JRE 6 dialog. I've never bothered to check why it is that way.

If you link with `-ljvm`, replace this with `-ljli`. If you use `dlopen` together with `dlsym` just use the other library name there.

Comment: I set SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-ljli"), where before it was -ljvm, however nothing changed. I don't use dlopen or dlsym in my code, but other code I link to from some github projects use both. Could that be the reason perhaps?

Comment: You could check with `otool` if libjvm is still referenced in any of your binaries