# Compiling JNI application on Mac OSX - No Java Runtime Present

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface

I have a C++ application that uses JNI to create a Java virtual machine.  I have the latest version of Java installed - JDK 8-144.  If I run "java -version" it comes up and tells me that Java Hotspot 8 is the JVM.  I have JAVA_HOME defined in the .profile file, and it works -- JAVA_HOME points to the JDK8-144 folder.

My application is including jni.h from the latest JDK.  Our code creates a JVM with the JNI_VERSION_1_8 version flag.  On Windows, this compiles and works perfectly.

The problem is that when we compile this code on the Mac, and use the JVM Framework for linking, we end up with an executable that, when run, says that there's "No Java Runtime present" and a dialog comes up that says we need to install the Version 6 JVM.  This happens if we run the application from either the Bash terminal or from XCode.

I've researched this and there are other people who have had this identical issue.  Everyone seems to suggest that JAVA_HOME needs to be pointing to the correct place, and mine is.  Again, java -version works correctly.  The whole thing is quite puzzling.

Does anyone know the right way to solve this?  I've tried two different Macs with identical results.  They are both running the latest version of macOS Sierra.

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490588/2543253 (and always link with Oracle libraries, not Apple's framework)

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for your help.  I've spent some time on this and unfortunately I'm having trouble linking to the Oracle libraries.

Comment: I added libjli.dylib to the project, and it links, but when I run the project it cannot find the library - because it's looking for the @rpath.  I read up on this and I found the setting in XCode to set the run path, and it sort-of seems to work, but now when the code tries to load the JVM, it spits out this error: "Error: could not find libjava.dylib"  Forgive me, I am not very skilled on the Mac.  What is the correct way to link to the Oracle JVM?

Comment: Last time I checked, the only way to find the libs when linked into the executable was to use DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH. I propose to use `dlopen`/`dlsym` instead. This way you can use all sorts of clever stuff to find the libraries at runtime.